# MySQL <> not working - returning those results

Tags: mysql, operators

I'm having a problem with the <> (NOT) operator.

I'm trying to retrieve rows where the habbo_name does not equal the two given, however it is still returning those rows. Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I could fix this?

Code:

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT `user_id`, `rank`, `habbo_name`, `rating`, `branch` FROM `personnel` WHERE status='active' AND `rating` LIKE '%(SDP%'  OR `rating` LIKE '%/SDP)%' AND (`habbo_name` <> '-Jose,' AND `habbo_name` <> 'tharuka$')  AND status='active' ORDER BY `habbo_name`";
        $result = $con->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
                while($row = $result->fetch()) {
                    echo "<b>SDP:</b>&nbsp" . htmlspecialchars($row['habbo_name']) . "<br>";
                }
?>
```

Result:

```
SDP: -Jose,
SDP: -Wyatt-
SDP: CPT.Black
SDP: Dr.Jacobson
SDP: Malwarebyte 
SDP: NShadow
SDP: tharuka$ (Dudestetson)
```

Comment: In SQL, the "`<>`" is an inequality comparison. The logical NOT operator is identified by the keyword "`NOT`" or a exclamation point ("!") which precedes an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`, so when mixing both operators one generally needs to include parentheses to enforce one's desired logic.  As things stand, your filter expression is evaluated as:

```
WHERE (
            status = 'active'
        AND rating LIKE '%(SDP%'
      ) OR (
            rating LIKE '%/SDP)%'
        AND habbo_name <> '-Jose,'
        AND habbo_name <> 'tharuka$'
        AND status = 'active'
      )
```

I suspect your want instead:

```
WHERE status = 'active'
  AND (rating LIKE '%(SDP%' OR rating LIKE '%/SDP)%')
  AND habbo_name <> '-Jose,' AND habbo_name <> 'tharuka$'
```

In this case, one can use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator to simplify the conditions on `habbo_name`:

```
WHERE status = 'active'
  AND (rating LIKE '%(SDP%' OR rating LIKE '%/SDP)%')
  AND habbo_name NOT IN ('-Jose,', 'tharuka$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this AND with an OR

```
(`habbo_name` <> '-Jose,' AND `habbo_name` <> 'tharuka$')
```

to

```
(`habbo_name` <> '-Jose,' OR `habbo_name` <> 'tharuka$')
```

Or you can use the following

```
`habbo_name` NOT IN ('-Jose,','tharuka$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for results which either:

1) have a status which equals 'active' and a rating like '%(SDP%'

**OR**

2) have a rating like '%/SDP)%' and where habbo_name aren't equal to -Jose / tharuka$

if -Jose / tharuka$'s ratings are 'active' and their rating's are like '%(SDP%', they will still be returned